# Representing any collection of points/sets as convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, connectedness

I've long been fascinated by the following images of European bodies:

[image: Supranational bodies of Europe]

I was wondering: would this work for any combination of countries and organizations?

If it helps, this could be expressed sloppily but formally as follows:

Given $n$ groups, and $m$ points which can each be represented as $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, where $x_i = binary(x$ in group $i)$,
Does there exist a mapping of the points onto $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a projection of the groups onto convex sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that $projectedpoint_j \in convexset_k$ iff ${(point_j)}_k = 1$?

If not, what is the minimum dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ needed for a given $m, n$?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is if every hypergraph can be represented in the plane in the usual way hypergraphs are represented. It can, you just need to draw a shape for each of the groups that only envelops the points in the group. Here is a drawing of a representation of a hypergraph:

[image]

Comment: It's worthy of note that even if we get the inclusion of the identified points right, we might get the intersections wrong; i.e. two regions might intersect despite having no identified points in the intersection.

Comment: that is interesting, can you give an example of a hypergraph that is not drawable respecting the property that the spaces of hyperedges intersect if and only if the hyperedges interesect?

Comment: Any non-planar graph suffices. There are probably more interesting examples too.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.

Comment: Sorry, I meant convex sets. Can you update your answer?

Comment: It's still true, place your vertices in a regular n-gon and take the convex hull of the vertices you want to be in the area of each group.

Comment: I never took topology, so I'll have to do some research before accepting :-)

Comment: you don't need topology, just place the vertices in a regular n-gon, suppose you want to draw a convex space that contains exactly vertices $v_1,v_2\dots v_n$. Then take the convex hull of those vertices and you'll get a convex subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that contains exactly the vertices $v_1,v_2\dots v_n$